# Iterate through endpoints of div in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am trying to find a target endpoint of a div in jsPlumb so I can connect it to another div. How do I iterate through the endpoints of a div?

Here's what I am trying

```
function getTargetEndpointOfDiv(divId)
{
var endpoints = $scope.jsPlumbInstance.selectEndpoints(divId)

for (var i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++)
{
  var point = endpoints[i]

  if (point.isTarget && point.connections.length == 0)
    return point
}

return null
}
```

My issue is that the variable "endpoints" always is an array of length 0 and is not just endpoint information. When I look into the endpoints I only see a bunch of functions and no variable information. I'm not sure where the endpoint information is stored in the array I have in endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var endpoints = plumbInstance.getEndpoints(divId);
```

Gets the list of Endpoints for a given element.

***Parameters:***

el String | Element | Selector

The element to get endpoints for.

***Returns:***

Endpoint[]:

An array of Endpoints for the specified element.

**References :**

https://github.com/nitinsurana/jsPlumb-Persistence/blob/master/jsplumb-persistence-plugin.js
https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbInstance.html#method_getEndpoints